# "conal" vs "conical"

Tags: meaning, mathematics

Is there any difference in meaning, usage or frequency between the words "conal" and "conical" within a mathematical context, i.e. when talking about cones?

Comment: The OED has no entry for "conal". Where did you find it? (Name of the book and some context.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, "conal" is practically unused. For this reason alone, I would stick to "conical."

See [Google Ngram for 1800 to 2000](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conal%2Cconical&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconical%3B%2Cc0) (I couldn't figure out how to embed this.)

EDIT!

As the learned [wfaull](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/11796/wfaulk]) suggests, in math, we will invariably refer to the circle, ellipse, parabola, and hyperbola as "conic sections" or sometimes just "conics." The words "conal" and "conical" are not used per se in math - conical is used in design, drafting, and physics, amoung other subjects, but I have still never seen "conal." Ever.

Comment: Simply "conic" seems to be used in most mathematical cases: "conic sections", for example.  There is also the "conical frustrum" though.